# Regression Discontinuity Design equation

Tags: regression, applied-econometrics, rdd

[image]Dear all,
I found this equation to estimate a RDD in a paper. $(f_i-f_z)$ is the running variable, hence $\alpha$ should be the slope to the left of the cutoff and $\lambda$ the variation in the slope between the left and the right of the cutoff for the function. But what does it mean the term associated with $\eta$?

Comment: look again. Is $\alpha$ a slope or an intercept?

Answer (score 1):

The slope for $f_i \leq f_z$ is $- \eta$, as the difference is reversed, with $f_i$ being the term with the negative sign.

From the cutoff, these two new terms “activate”:

- $\alpha$, which is a constant. Assuming $\alpha > 0$, the would-be-intercept (assuming the right regression extended all the way to the left) would be higher than the intercept of the left regression. The original intercept is $\delta$, this “would-be-intercept” is $\delta + \alpha$.
- $\lambda (f_i - f_z)$ which is a linear term on the difference: From the cutoff, this term adds a slope of $\lambda$. With this, we get that the slope of the regression (on $f_i$) becomes $\lambda - \eta$.